# Windows desktop Calculator automation test not working with MS Visual studio-WinAppDriver-Appium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, appium, winappdriver

I am newbie to WinAppDriver-Appium automation test.
I am just trying with simple C# sharp code to auto test windows desktop calculator. Please find below code.

CalculatorSession.cs

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using System;

namespace CalculatorTest
{
public class CalculatorSession
{
    // Note: append /wd/hub to the URL if you're directing the test at Appium
    private const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
    private const string CalculatorAppId = 
    "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
    protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

    public static void Setup(TestContext context)
    {
        // Launch Calculator application if it is not yet launched
        if (session == null)
        {
            // Create a new session to bring up an instance of the Calculator application
            // Note: Multiple calculator windows (instances) share the same process Id
            AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", CalculatorAppId);

            session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), options);


            /* AppiumOptions appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
             appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", CalculatorAppId);
             appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
             session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);*/

            Assert.IsNotNull(session);

            // Set implicit timeout to 1.5 seconds to make element search to retry every 500 ms for at most three times
            session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
        }
    }

    public static void TearDown()
    {
        // Close the application and delete the session
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.Quit();
            session = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

ScenarioStandard.cs

```
   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
   using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
   using System.Threading;
   using System;

   namespace CalculatorTest
   {
       [TestClass]
       public class ScenarioStandard : CalculatorSession
       {
           private static WindowsElement header;
           private static WindowsElement calculatorResult;

           [TestMethod]
           public void Addition()
           {
               // Find the buttons by their names and click them in sequence to perform 1 + 7 = 8
               session.FindElementByName("One").Click();
               session.FindElementByName("Plus").Click();
               session.FindElementByName("Seven").Click();
               session.FindElementByName("Equals").Click();
               Assert.AreEqual("8", GetCalculatorResultText());
           }

           [TestMethod]
           public void Division()
           {
               // Find the buttons by their accessibility ids and click them in sequence to perform 88 / 11 = 8
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num8Button").Click();
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num8Button").Click();
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("divideButton").Click();
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num1Button").Click();
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num1Button").Click();
               session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("equalButton").Click();
               Assert.AreEqual("8", GetCalculatorResultText());
           }

           [TestMethod]
           public void Multiplication()
           {
               // Find the buttons by their names using XPath and click them in sequence to perform 9 x 9 = 81
               session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Nine']").Click();
               session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Multiply by']").Click();
               session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Nine']").Click();
               session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Equals']").Click();
               Assert.AreEqual("81", GetCalculatorResultText());
           }

           [TestMethod]
           public void Subtraction()
           {
               // Find the buttons by their accessibility ids using XPath and click them in sequence to perform 9 - 1 = 8
                 session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"num9Button\"]").Click();
                 session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"minusButton\"]").Click();
                 session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"num1Button\"]").Click();
                 session.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"equalButton\"]").Click();
                 Assert.AreEqual("8", GetCalculatorResultText());
            }

           [TestMethod]
           [DataRow("One", "Plus", "Seven", "8")]
           [DataRow("Nine", "Minus", "One", "8")]
           [DataRow("Eight", "Divide by", "Eight", "1")]
           public void Templatized(string input1, string operation, string input2, string expectedResult)
           {
               // Run sequence of button presses specified above and validate the results
               session.FindElementByName(input1).Click();
               session.FindElementByName(operation).Click();
               session.FindElementByName(input2).Click();
               session.FindElementByName("Equals").Click();
               Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, GetCalculatorResultText());
           }

           [ClassInitialize]
           public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
           {
               // Create session to launch a Calculator window
               Setup(context);

               // Identify calculator mode by locating the header
               try
               {
                   header = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Header");
               }
               catch
               {
                   header = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("ContentPresenter");
               }

               // Ensure that calculator is in standard mode
               if (!header.Text.Equals("Standard", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               {
                   session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("TogglePaneButton").Click();
                   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                   var splitViewPane = session.FindElementByClassName("SplitViewPane");
                   splitViewPane.FindElementByName("Standard Calculator").Click();
                   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                   Assert.IsTrue(header.Text.Equals("Standard",               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
               }

               // Locate the calculatorResult element
               calculatorResult = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CalculatorResults");
               Assert.IsNotNull(calculatorResult);
           }

           [ClassCleanup]
           public static void ClassCleanup()
           {
               TearDown();
           }

           [TestInitialize]
           public void Clear()
           {
               session.FindElementByName("Clear").Click();
               Assert.AreEqual("0", GetCalculatorResultText());
           }

           private string GetCalculatorResultText()
           {
               return calculatorResult.Text.Replace("Display is", string.Empty).Trim();
           }
       }
}
```

I am using MS visual studio IDE and created project using template "Unit Test App ( Universal Windows )".
When I run above code it just opens empty window like below.
[UnitTestProject.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdjaD.png)

I want my code to open calculator automatically and should perform tasks mentioned in code.
How to make it work. Please guide.